# Clearing a specific tabstop in a range of paragraphs

Tags: vba, ms-word, tabstop

In my TOC fields, a tab stop is being automatically added by another program when the Word document is generated. The tab stop is in the wrong place.

I can use the following to find and select each TOC field:

```
Dim doc As Document
Dim fld As Field
Dim rng As Range

Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each fld In doc.Fields
    If fld.Type = wdFieldTOC Then
        fld.Select
    End If
Next
```

However, if I try to remove that tabstop from the selected TOC, it tells "This TabStops collection has mixed tab settings."

I need a way to iterate through each paragraph in the selected TOC, remove tabstop B and add TabStop B. I thought that was going to be the easy part, but I must be doing something wrong. Please help!! Thanks!!

Comment: Please clarify `remove tabstop B and add TabStop B`. What's the exptected location for TabStop A / B.

Answer (score 0):

You already find the field that defined the TOC. The content of this field is a Range and can be read using the `Result` property.

The range of the TOC contains a paragraph for every line (entry). Every of those paragraphs has tab definitions.

I assume that a TOC paragraph should contain only one tab stop, the one that positions the page numbers at the right (for Left to Right reading). It is right aligned and has a "." (dot) as leading character.

The following code will remove (clear) all tabs from the TOC paragraphs and add only the one right-aligned for the page numbers. As you need to specify the tab position (in points) and this can vary depending on your page layout, I use the position of the last tab of the first paragraph. Maybe you have to adapt the code to your needs.

```
Sub CorrectTOC()
    Dim fld As Field
    For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If fld.Type = wdFieldTOC Then
            SetTOCTabs fld.Result
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub SetTOCTabs(r As Range)
    Dim tabPos As Double
    Dim p As Paragraph
    For Each p In r.Paragraphs
        If tabPos = 0 Then 
            ' Save tab position if not already done.
             tabPos = p.TabStops(p.TabStops.Count).Position
        End If
        ' Remove all Tabs and add only one (right aligned)
        p.TabStops.ClearAll   
        p.TabStops.Add tabPos, wdAlignTabRight, Leader:=1
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**
If it is only about changing the position of the tab stop at the right, it's easy, just change the `Position`-property.

```
Sub SetTOCTabs(r As Range)
    Const TabPosRight As Double = 468

    Dim p As Paragraph
    For Each p In r.Paragraphs
        p.TabStops(p.TabStops.Count).Position = TabPosRight
    Next
End Sub
```

If however, only some of your TOC entries have a left Tab stop that you want to keep or only some of the TOC entries have that invalid right Tab stop, maybe this can be your solution:

```
Sub SetTOCTabs(r As Range)
    Const TabPosRight As Double = 468

    Dim p As Paragraph
    For Each p In r.Paragraphs
        Dim tabPosLeft As Double
        If p.TabStops.Count > 1 Then
            tabPosLeft = p.TabStops(1).Position
        Else
            tabPosLeft = -1
        End If
        p.TabStops.ClearAll
        ' Add left tab stop
        If tabPosLeft > 0 Then
            p.TabStops.Add tabPosLeft, wdAlignTabLeft
        End If
        ' Add right tab stop
        p.TabStops.Add tabPos, wdAlignTabRight, Leader:=1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! However, I have 2 tabs. One is early on and changes from paragraph to paragraph. I need to leave that one intact. The second one is the one that I need to be eliminated. It is at 396pt. I need to remove only that tab and replace it with a right tab at 468pt.

Comment: @Troy: See my update. Check if one of the two routines fits your need. Else it should be easy enough to modify them

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!! However, I must be doing something wrong. When I try to run either of those, nothing happens, except my computer makes a sound. I tried stepping through them, and again, nothing happens but the sound. No error. I tried running other macros in the same file and other files, and they run fine. Thoughts on why?

Comment: No idea what "makes a sound." should be. If you are stepping through: Is the TOC found at all? Is `SetTOCTabs` called? Is the `For Each p In r.Paragraphs`-loop entered? Are the statement to clear/set the TabStops executed?

Comment: Just found the problem. It does not like the "(r As Range)" next to the sub name. Take it out, and it works fine.

Comment: Sub SetTOCTabs()
    Const TabPosRight As Double = 540

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection.Range
    
    Dim p As Paragraph
    For Each p In r.Paragraphs
        Dim tabPosLeft As Double
        If p.TabStops.Count > 1 Then
            tabPosLeft = p.TabStops(1).Position
        Else
            tabPosLeft = -1
        End If
        p.TabStops.ClearAll
        ' Add left tab stop
        If tabPosLeft > 0 Then
            p.TabStops.Add tabPosLeft, wdAlignTabLeft
        End If
        p.TabStops.Add TabPosRight, wdAlignTabRight, Leader:=1
    Next
End Sub

Comment: The problem is that it is putting a tab at 5.47" instead of 6.5". It does this no matter what value I put in for TabPosRight. Thoughts?